# Does IBM's Rational Functional Tester (v 9.1) test web pages?

Tags: testing, functional-testing, rft, ibm-rational

I would like to know if I can access a website using a browser for testing purposes using RFT. For practice, I'm trying to use www.google.com.For example, can I automate a Google search using RFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can automate web pages with RFT. For an example see [A Rational Functional Tester project to test an HTML application](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJMXE_9.1.1/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.sample.doc/topics/r_sample_rtc.html).